# jQuery offset top is null in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I have a nice little function that will let me know if a element is visible in the DOM or not.

I am calling it every second using an interval and passing the argument:

```
setInterval(function(){
    if(isScrolledIntoView("#scene-1") == true){
       //do something
    }else{
       //do something else
    }
 },1000)

function isScrolledIntoView(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    var $window = $(window);

    var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
    var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

    var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemBottom <= docViewBottom) && (elemTop >= docViewTop));
}
```

It works great in chrome and firefox. But in IE I get an error on the statement:

`var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;`

I converted it to vanilla by this way:

```
var elemTop = document.getElementById(elem.replace("#", "")).offsetTop;
```

In case that didnt work I also changed the whole thing to vanilla js and passed the id without the hash tag.

I am getting the error `0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'top' of undefined or null reference`

I do not understand why. I know the element exist on the DOM and the spelling is correct.

**************EDIT**********************

http://jsfiddle.net/ew0ewch3/

Comment: Can you provide a JSFIDDLE?

Comment: Yeah let me set it up. I am running IE edge on WIndows 7. I haven't tested 9 or 10 yet.

Comment: I added the jsFiddle

Comment: Not answering the actual question here, but why are you triggering this on every second? This is killing your performance. The element can't be visible without a scroll, right? Trigger it on the users' scroll.

Comment: I am triggering every second to detect something. I am going to get it working better as far as performance. But I have to get it to work first. This was the easiest set up as far as getting it going.

Comment: You say "I am running IE edge on Windows 7". I guess you actually mean IE11 in "edge" mode.

Comment: Yeah. I ended up going with another solution anyway. If you run the fiddle in IE it works great. It was an error in my code.